# How to use awk to parse urls and pass to curl to download it?

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I want to download a binary from https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin. but the url will redirect to another address, so I use the awk to parse it. e.g.

```
curl -I https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin/blob/master/dist/newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz\?raw\=true | awk '/Location:/ {print $2}'
```

And the result is as I expected, e.g.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin/raw/master/dist/newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz
```

The real address is parsed. so I just want to use curl to download it. but I always got fail. 
My os is osx El Capitan (I don't have wget).

```
curl -I https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin/blob/master/dist/newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz\?raw\=true | awk '/Location:/ {curl -O $2}'
```

p.s. 
I tried to download the binary directly by curl, but still failed. The downloaded the file was incorrect size and content.

```
curl -O https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin/raw/master/dist/newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz
```

Comment: In you 2nd to last example, you can't just type the words "curl -O" in your awk script and expect it to work, and its not recommended to run programs from "inside" awk (although you can). You're last example seems the most likely to succeed, but  did you try  `curl -O outFile.tar.gz https://....` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`curl` has switch `-L` which can handle redirect.

So, this should work:

```
curl -L https://github.com/sschwartzman/newrelic-unix-plugin/blob/master/dist/newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz\?raw\=true -o newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yes, with your command, I can download the gz file but I got an error like "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz" and the file name is "newrelic_unix_plugin.tar.gz?raw=true". I have to rename it to a tar.gz file and extract. How to resolve the name issue? thx.

Comment: Should use '-o' instead of '-O'